# Optimizing large db merge using split() function

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, split, large-data

I need to perform a conceptually straightforward double left-merge followed by a simple series of matching functions (*See*: Straightforward Solution). However, given the DBs I have to merge are large in size I tried to unpack the merging procedure by considering a for-loop that does the trick but is inefficient to say the least (*See*: For-loops Solution).

Is there a solution splitting and naming at least the largest db?
Below there is a toy example.

For reference, in my data:

db_m1 ~50k lines (for ~5k unique m1)

db_m2 ~25k lines (for ~5k unique m1 and m2)

db_p  ~100m lines

```
set.seed(0)
db_m1 <- data.frame(
  y=rep(1,20),
  id=sort(rep(paste0("id_",c(letters[1:4])),5)),
  m1=rep(c(1,2),10),
  x1=sample(LETTERS, 20, TRUE),
  x2=sample(LETTERS, 20, TRUE))

set.seed(0) 
db_m2 <- data.frame(y=rep(1,20),
                    m1=sample(c(1:5),20,TRUE),
                    m2=sample(c(6:10),20,TRUE))
set.seed(0)
db_p <- data.frame(m2=sample(c(6:10),100,TRUE),
                   y1=sample(LETTERS, 100,TRUE),
                   y2=sample(LETTERS, 10,TRUE))
```

Straightforward Solution :

```
final_dplyr <- db_m1 %>%
  dplyr::left_join(db_m2) %>%
  dplyr::left_join(db_p) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(match_1=ifelse(x1==y1|x1==y2,1,0),
         match_2=ifelse(x2==y1|x2==y2,1,0),
         sum_matches=mapply(sum,match_1,match_2),
         final_1 = ifelse(as.numeric(sum_matches)>=1,1,0),
         final_2 = ifelse(as.numeric(sum_matches)>=2,1,0)) %>%
  group_by(id,m2) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(n_p=n(),
                n_p=ifelse(all(is.na(y1)),NA,n_p)) %>% 
  group_by(y,id,m1,m2,n_p) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(match_1=sum(match_1,na.rm = T),
                   match_2=sum(match_2,na.rm = T),
                   final_1 = sum(final_1),
                   final_2 = sum(final_2))
```

For-loops Solution:

```
fn_final <- function(db_m1,db_m2,db_p) {
  
  matches_final <- vector("list",length = length(unique(db_m1$y)))  
  for(i in 1:length(unique(db_m1$y))){
    
    matches <- vector("list",length = length(unique(db_m1$m1)))  
    for(j in 1:length(unique(db_m1$m1))){
      
      temp_db_m1 <- db_m1 %>% dplyr::filter(y==unique(db_m1$y)[i], m1==unique(db_m1$m1)[j])
      temp_db_m2 <- db_m2  %>% dplyr::filter(y==unique(db_m1$y)[i], m1==unique(db_m1$m1)[j])
      m_vector <- unique(temp_db_m2$m2)
      temp_db_p <- db_p %>% 
        dplyr::filter(m2 %in% m_vector) 
      
      final <- db_m1 %>%
        dplyr::left_join(db_m2) %>%
        dplyr::left_join(db_p) %>%      dplyr::mutate(match_1=ifelse(x1==y1|x1==y2,1,0),
                      match_2=ifelse(x2==y1|x2==y2,1,0),
                      sum_matches=mapply(sum,match_1,match_2),
                      final_1 = ifelse(as.numeric(sum_matches)>=1,1,0),
                      final_2 = ifelse(as.numeric(sum_matches)>=2,1,0)) %>%
        group_by(id,m2) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(n_p=n(),
                      n_p=ifelse(all(is.na(y1)),NA,n_p)) %>% 
        group_by(y,id,m1,m2,n_p) %>% 
        dplyr::summarise(match_1=sum(match_1,na.rm = T),
                         match_2=sum(match_2,na.rm = T),
                         final_1 = sum(final_1),
                         final_2 = sum(final_2)) 
      
      
      matches[[j]] <- final
    }
    matches_all <- do.call(rbind, matches)
    matches_final[[i]] <- matches_all
  }
  final <- do.call(rbind, matches_final) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(n_p)) %>% 
    unique()
  return(final)
}

final_for <- fn_final(db_m1,db_m2,db_p)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution, should it be optimized further?

```
db_m1_s <- split(db_m1, f = list(db_m1$y,db_m1$m1))
db_m2_s <- split(db_m2, f = list(db_m2$y,db_m2$m1))
db_p_s <- split(db_p, f = list(db_p$m2))

match_fn <- function(temp_db_m1,temp_db_m2,temp_db_p){
  final <- temp_db_m1 %>%
    dplyr::left_join(temp_db_m2) %>%
    dplyr::left_join(temp_db_p) %>%      
    dplyr::mutate(match_1=ifelse(x1==y1|x1==y2,1,0),
                  match_2=ifelse(x2==y1|x2==y2,1,0),
                  sum_matches=mapply(sum,match_1,match_2),
                  final_1 = ifelse(as.numeric(sum_matches)>=1,1,0),
                  final_2 = ifelse(as.numeric(sum_matches)>=2,1,0)) %>%
    group_by(id,m2) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(n_p=n(),
                  n_p=ifelse(all(is.na(y1)),NA,n_p)) %>% 
    group_by(y,id,m1,m2,n_p) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(match_1=sum(match_1,na.rm = T),
                     match_2=sum(match_2,na.rm = T),
                     final_1 = sum(final_1),
                     final_2 = sum(final_2)) 
  
  return(final)
}
fn_final <- function(db_m1,db_m1_s,db_m2_s,db_p_s) {

  m <- names(db_m1_s)
  matches_1 <- vector("list",length = length(m))  
  for(i in 1:length(m)){
    
    temp_db_m1 <- db_m1_s[[m[i]]]
    temp_db_m2 <- db_m2_s[[m[i]]]
    
    n <- as.character(sort(unique(temp_db_m2$m2)))
    
    matches_2 <- vector("list",length = length(n))  
    for(j in 1:length(n)){
     
      temp_db_p <- db_p_s[[n[j]]]
  
      final <- match_fn(temp_db_m1,temp_db_m2,temp_db_p)
      matches_2[[j]] <- final
    }
    matches_all <- do.call(rbind, matches_2)
    matches_1[[i]] <- matches_all
  }
  matches_0 <- do.call(rbind, matches_1) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(n_p)) %>% 
    unique()
  return(matches_0)
}

final_for <- fn_final(db_m1,db_m1_s,db_m2_s,db_p_s)
```